# Integral of $e^{\frac{y}{x}}$

Tags: integration

How can we evaluate the following?

$$\int e^{\frac{y}{x}}\ \mathrm dy$$

An explanation of the answer would be helpful.

The answer I got is $ x  e^{y/x}$.

But not sure about the steps used for obtaining the answer...

Comment: With regards to which variable are you integrating? $x$? $y$? Both? If so, in which order?

Comment: In any event, you forgot the constant!

Comment: integrating with respect to dy

Comment: Change variable $y=z x$ and it will becopme easy.

Comment: How did you get that answer? If you don't show the steps, we can't tell if they are correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\begin{align}
\int_{- \infty} e^{\frac{y}{x}}dy &=  \int_{- \infty}^y e^{\frac{t}{x}}dt \\
&= \int_{- \infty}^y e^{\frac{xu}{x}}d(xu) \\
&= x \int_{- \infty}^{y \over x} e^u d u \\
&= x \vert_{u = {- \infty}}^{y \over x} e^u \\
&= x \ e^{y \over x}
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 2):

Since this a task on finding a primitive, you can always check you candidate answer by taking (partial in your case) derivative.

Comment: When I saw this question in the queue, that was my thought (+1)

Comment: @robjohn: thanks! nice to see you active here on mse

Answer (score -1):

First note that
$$\int a^t\ \mathrm dt=\frac{a^t}{\ln a}+C$$
Therefore
$$\int e^{\frac{y}{x}}\ \mathrm dy=\int \left(e^{\frac{1}{x}}\right)^y\ \mathrm dy$$
$$=\frac{\left(e^{\frac{1}{x}}\right)^y}{\ln e^{\frac{1}{x}}}+C=xe^{\frac{y}{x}}+C$$

Comment: Would the downvoter care to comment?